# How to reference a sql server with a backslash (\) in its name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, linked-server

**Givens:**

- One SQL Server is named: `DevServerA`
- Another is named: `DevServerB\2K5`

**Problem:**

From `DevServerA`, how can I write a query that references `DevServerB\2K5`?

I tried a sample, dummy query (running it from `DevServerA`):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *  
FROM DevServerB\2K5.master.sys.tables
```

**And I get the error:**

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '\.'.
```

However, I know my syntax is almost correct, since the other way around works (running this query from `DevServerB\2K5`):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *  
FROM DevServerA.master.sys.tables
```

Please help me figure out how to reference `DevServerB\2K5` from `DevServerA`. Thanks.

Comment: Technically, slash is (/) and backslash is (\\).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In 4 part names, the first part if the name of a linked server (ie. a metadata object), not the name of a server (ie. a host name). So you can name your linked server FOO and have him point at the host BAR, or at the instance FOO\BAR. And even if you name the linked server object to contain a slash, you can still use it in a multi-part name by simply quoting the name:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *  
FROM [DevServerB\2K5].master.sys.tables
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using square brackets:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *  
FROM [DevServerB\2K5].master.sys.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

On SQL SERVER 2005, the following happened:
Entry of:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *   
FROM [DevServerB\2K5].master.sys.tables
```

Is changed to

```
SELECT TOP 1 *   
FROM DevServerB\2K5.master.sys.tables
```

by SQL Server system and you still get the error message:
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

I tried it with a linked server named in two different ways:
'[DevServerB\2K5]'  and 'DevServerB\2K5'

Does anybody have any other ideas?

Thank you Alan Robertson

CORRECTION added the next day:  I was wrong, partially. When one tries to create a view using a SQL statement like:

```
SELECT  *
FROM [DevServerB\2K5].TestDB.dbo.tables
```

then the [ and ] are removed and one cannot save the view, 
BUT if one just writes a query using the same SQL string then it works correctly.

I was also able to execute a SQL statement like:

```
INSERT INTO [DevServerB\2K5].TestDB.dbo.tables ( ... ) ...
```

I can do what I wanted, but it would have been much better if I could have saved a view and used a view that would then be used for SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE of the table in the [DevServerB\2K5].TestDB database
from the original server where I tried and failed to create a view because of the '\' .

-ASR-

Comment: Regarding the problem with SQL Server 2005 (which I also ran into) you can use CREATE or ALTER VIEW statements. There seems to be a bug in the designer that prevents from saving the definition, so you'll have to do it manually ;-)