# SQL Server sys.servers where name has \ in it

Tags: sql, sql-server

The name of a link server in sys.servers has a \ in it. When I try to pass that to openquery() it gives a syntax error. I've tried escaping it with another \ with no luck. Any ideas on how I can get openquery() to work where the linked server name has a \ in it?

Comment: Did you try wrapping the server name with brackets?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549313/how-to-reference-a-sql-server-with-a-backslash-in-its-name

Comment: Are you using the linked server name in your query (i.e: not the physical name)?

Comment: It is a sql or c # problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794095/sql-connect-to-linked-server-with-named-instance

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping it in brackets worked [test/test]. Thank you.